# Enforcing value-contraints during integration

Tags: matlab, delay, numerical-methods, solver, differential-equations

Sorry for the collection of keywords, there is no specific tag for "delay-differential equations" (and I doubt it would be useful to create one).

I am integrating a function using `dde23` in Matlab, and I have looked in `ddeset` for the options that are available, but I can't find a way to enforce value-constraints on the solution.

What I mean by "value-constraint" is that my function is not allowed to take values outside of the interval `[0,1]`, but the differential system itself is continuous and depending on the integration scheme, the numerical solution can sometimes take values outside that interval.

I know I can restrict the values *a posteriori*, but I would like to enforce these constraints directly after each successful integration step. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure if this is more suited in the mathematics SE

Comment: @AnderBiguri This is purely a programming question though, but I'm happy to move it if other people think it should.

Comment: Yea maybe you are rigth. Leave it here for the moment.

Comment: The function dde23 is not encrypted and can be modified. So maybe you find the place where each integration step is computed and add there your constraint

Comment: Sorry, but if you force values upon your result in the middle of the integration process, that means that your result doesn't satisfy the equation anymore, isn't it? (generally speaking about any differential equation, not necessarily this kind)

Comment: @RobertStettler That's a good idea actually, I was just hoping there would be an "undocumented" option to do this automatically, but it looks like I'll have to get my hands dirty. :/

Comment: I kind of agree with @CST-Link that imposing the condition *after* a successful integration step may/will lead to an inconsistent scheme.  But I do think imposing the condition within the ODE function itself is possibly the best way since `dde23` will adjust the time step for the discontinuity and satisfaction of the system.  Whether it's correct or not, I know not.

Answer (score 1):

One way to enforce solution with limited range is to look for solutions that are images trough a function with limited codomain (like `atan`).

For example, if you want the values of the solution `y(t)` between `YMIN` and `YMAX`, then look for solutions

```
y(t) = (YMAX+YMIN)/2 + (YMAX-YMIN)*atan(u(t))/pi
```

Rewrite your delayed system in the new variable `u`, give it to `dde23` and pray to Cauchy that such solutions exist.

Comment: Oh my :) I was looking for solutions that wouldn't involve rewriting my system. Thanks a lot for the advice though, I just don't think it's a good idea to use an arbitrary mapping of R to [0,1] (I could essentially take any sigmoid function following your approach). I think RobertStettler might be right actually, the easiest way might be to include my own code into a local copy of dde23.

Comment: @Sh3ljohn Then again, limiting the value in the middle of integration will break the differential equation, because the increment/correction says to the solution "go up!", while the limitation says "not today!". The limitation wins, and the equation is sad. Next time it will try again, to the same amount of success. Which would mean actually continuously rewriting the initial conditions to fit the constraint (because every forced value becomes initial condition for the next iteration, and has nothing to do with the old condition/solution).

Comment: :D I really like your way of talking about this, and I think you are right, I might give a try to your solution at some point.